# Controlling power with Isolated DC-DC Converter remote on off vs Relay

Tags: microcontroller, power, relay, dc-dc-converter

I am designing a simple PCB with multiple DC to DC converters. One in particular is an isolated DC to DC converter with a remote on / off pin (to turn the converter on and off).

Currently i have in mind of connecting that converter to a general purpose or SS relay, controlled by arduino microcontroller chip, Atmega 328P. This will be used to open and close a mechanical/solenoid lock.

However, is it a good idea to skip the relay, and wire up the chip directly to the remote on/off of the converter? Or is it better to keep the relay? is the remote on/off pin of the converter isolated? Thanks.

Attached is the datasheet to the converter

http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0aca/0900766b80acafda.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, is it a good idea to skip the relay, and wire up the chip
>   directly to the remote on/off of the converter?

I consider this as a contender - the on/off pin isn't isolated from the input end of the Traco circuit so if you need to control this with some isolation I'd consider using an opto-isolator. Please also make sure that when you deactivate the Traco, any back-emf from the solenoid doesn't try to push current back into the output pins to any great extent. You could use a zener diode across the output of the Traco to largely prevent this from happening. Choose a zener voltage that is a couple of volts higher than what the output voltage from the Traco is.

Comment: Given the remote pin is isolated on the input side from the output of the converter, will the back EMF from the solenoid to converter output affect microcontroller? In addition, the converter power the lock is 12V Max 1A, and the controller it self is powered by a non isolated converter at 5V 1A, all the converter GNDS are connected to a ground plane (except the isolated all Vout- ), do i have to worry about ground loops or anything that would affect the microcontroller or the voltage reference that the microcontroller uses? Btw thanks for the  clear answer

Comment: The remote pin IS NOT isolated from the input side of the converter. Any load changes will have no effect on the microcontroller should you operate as I suggest. But, in the absence of any circuit idea about your target circuit I shouldn't really comment. Post a scheme or a new question if you want new answers to those not originally raised.

Comment: OK so someone has downvoted this answer - any explanation?

Comment: Interesting, must have been 2 downvotes, cause i pushed  +1.

Comment: @BuzzyBee until you attain a reputation of 10 upvotes/downvotes are not registered. However, if you have anything to ask about my answer then please do so (or formally accept the answer).

Comment: Ah okay, one last thing, when i follow your solution, is there a chance of grounding issues messing with the voltage reference? because the micro is going to be powered by a non-isolated 5v1a converter on the same PCB, but since the micro is hooked up via to the remote on off conv of the 12v1a converter, is that going to mess up voltage signals because they don't return to the exact same ground directly? (all converter input grounds are connected to the PCB ground plane)

Comment: What voltage reference? You hook the micro to the Traco on/off pin via an opto isolator if in any doubt.